# Can you say someone "never [VERB]s" if they used to in the past?

Tags: meaning, present-tense

If you say "never swears" as an example, can this include if someone has done it **in the past** but doesn’t do it consistently nor in recent time?

Answer (score 0):

[Never](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/never) is a long time, backward and forward.

If you say "Pat never swears," you are stating a fact that runs to both ends of time. If Pat has sworn in the past but doesn’t do it consistently now or recently, you'd have to add **anymore** to be clear you mean current times:

> "Pat never swears **any more**."

Comment: In US English, there is a distinction between ‘any more’ (used as a determiner), and ‘anymore’ (used as an adverb). In UK English, ‘anymore’ is typically considered incorrect, and any more is the correct spelling for both parts of speech.

Comment: You could add other clarifying words, such as 'these days', 'since he got fined for a public order offence', 'since his mother knocked him unconscious', etc.

Comment: I think the clarifying words can be in a later sentence, or not appear at all. I don't agree that "never" must extend to +/- infinity in a sentence with a present tense verb.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty When I was younger, some people used to say, about some men, after they died, _'he never married'_. There was a certain intonation.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* with a present-tense verb does carry an implication of *these days*. If we mean something like

> For all times *t* up to and including the present moment, uttering the statement “John doesn’t swear” at time *t* would be speaking a truth

Then we say *John has never sworn*.

If we wish to be clear that the valid times *t* don’t reach back to the moment of John’s birth (or maybe to the Big Bang?), we say, “John never swears these days” or, “John never swears anymore.” And if we wish to be clear that we make no claim about earlier times one way or the other, we can say, “Lately anyway, John never swears.”

Answer (score 0):

John never swears these days. But he used to.

John never swore in the past but he does now.

John has never sworn in my presence.

The adverbs never, always, often and other adverbs of frequency can be used in most tenses.